# One or Many Docker Containers for MySQL/PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, docker

I plan to build a docker environment running several business applications. Each application need a separate database. My question is:

Is it recommended to start a separate database container (e.g. mysql or postgres) for each application container? Or should I run only one database container and install several databases in it?

Is a docker-host with multiple mysql containers - each with one database - wasting CPU or memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker way is using separate and independent environment for each service. if you will use separate database for each application you can

- update DBMS independently
- make flexible scaling
- independent backups(with Extrabackup as example)
- you can completely brake one of databases and another applications will works fine.
- and so on.

But in **development** environment you can use single container for all databases.

Comment: My question also relates to whether such a scenario with multiple MySQL containers is wasting CPU or memory on the docker-host?

Comment: yes of couse  multiple instances of something wasting more CPU and memory. But how many will be wasted depends on may factors.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a separate container for each database, even in development. Using `docker-compose` this becomes relatively trivial